# AWS lightsail snapshot moving

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services

My wordpress site that is hosted on lightsail got messed up by a plugin and my homepage is gone. Have a snapshot and want to revert back. I have moved it to another instance and the Wordpress isn't showing the same website that I thought it would. What should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by "Wordpress isn't showing the same website that I thought it would"? It's showing _something_? Is it _your_ website that it is showing? What do you mean by "have moved it to another instance"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.